# Cannot access CCArray from another method

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I'm new to Cocos2d-x and I had to pass an array between two CCScenes. I did that and got it like so:

```
CCScene* ClassicModeLayer::scene(CCArray *boltArray)
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    ClassicModeLayer *layer = ClassicModeLayer::create();

    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(layer);

    layer->mColorArray = CCArray::createWithCapacity(boltArray->count());
    layer->mColorArray->addObjectsFromArray(boltArray);
    mColorArray->retain();

    return scene;
}
```

But when I'm trying to access the `mColorArray` in another method like so:

```
CCInteger *value = (CCInteger*) mColorArray->objectAtIndex(0);
```

But it crashes. I'm guessing the memory allocation is being released. Is there anything else I should be doing? I tried retaining the array. But that didnt work.

Comment: sure, it crashes. I'd say the scope of layer is incorrect. You are creating layer locally to the `scene` function. No need to do the `retain()` for the array either.

Comment: Shouldn't you write `layer->mColorArray->retain();` instead of `mColorArray->retain();`? `createWithCapacity()` autoreleases the created array before it's returned. Is `CCScene* ClassicModeLayer::scene(CCArray *boltArray)` a static method?

Comment: @n-o-d Yes CCScene* ClassicModeLayer::scene(CCArray *boltArray) is a static method.

Comment: If scene() is static then mColorArray must be static, too. Right? Otherwise your code wouldn't compile. But then you probably don't want to copy any data since you can access the original anyway. Can you post parts of the ClassicModeLayer header and the part where ClassicModeLayer::scene() is called for clearification? Do you want mColorArray to be a non-static member?